# ARRAY in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ch04.median (arr ANY TYPE) AS ((
  SELECT IF(MOD(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2) = 0,
    ( arr[OFFSET(DIV(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2) - 1)] +
      arr[OFFSET(DIV(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2))])  / 2,
      arr[OFFSET(DIV(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2))] )
  FROM (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(x ORDER BY x) AS arr FROM UNNEST(arr) AS x)
));

SELECT 
  start_station_name,
  COUNT(*) AS num_trips,
  ch04.median(ARRAY_AGG(tripduration)) AS typical_duration
FROM `bigquery-public-data`.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips
GROUP BY start_station_name
HAVING num_trips > 1000
ORDER BY typical_duration DESC
LIMIT 10
```

**ch04** is just a random dataset I created which has the same location as the new york bike dataset

The preceding code works fine. But I noticed there is `FROM UNNEST(arr)` and `ARRAY_AGG(tripduration)`,
so I think as they form an `ARRAY` and then `UNNEST` the `ARRAY`, why not drop both? But the code below didn't work.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ch04.median (arr ANY TYPE) AS ((
  SELECT IF(MOD(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2) = 0,
    ( arr[OFFSET(DIV(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2) - 1)] +
      arr[OFFSET(DIV(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2))])  / 2,
      arr[OFFSET(DIV(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2))] )
  FROM (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(x ORDER BY x) AS arr FROM arr AS x)
));

SELECT 
  start_station_name,
  COUNT(*) AS num_trips,
  ch04.median(tripduration) AS typical_duration
FROM `bigquery-public-data`.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips
GROUP BY start_station_name
HAVING num_trips > 1000
ORDER BY typical_duration DESC
LIMIT 10
```

I get this error:

> Invalid value: Table name "arr" missing dataset while no default dataset is set in the request. at [1:1]

Can anyone help me wrap my head around this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately in this particular case you cannot avoid using UNNEST ...

If you really want to optimize your initial query - below is an option

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ch04.median (arr ANY TYPE) AS (
  IF(MOD(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2) = 0,
    ( arr[OFFSET(DIV(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2) - 1)] +
      arr[OFFSET(DIV(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2))])  / 2,
      arr[OFFSET(DIV(ARRAY_LENGTH(arr), 2))] )
);

SELECT 
  start_station_name,
  COUNT(*) AS num_trips,
  ch04.median(ARRAY_AGG(tripduration ORDER BY tripduration)) AS typical_duration
FROM `bigquery-public-data`.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips
GROUP BY start_station_name
HAVING num_trips > 1000
ORDER BY typical_duration DESC
LIMIT 10
```

As you can see in above query you supply already ordered array into your function - so all ordering stuff within the function can be removed

Comment: Mikhail, thank you for your answer. The optimization is beautiful. But I'm still wondering why. Cause if I were to come up with the second code and the code ran into an error, I would not know what's wrong. Like debugging a program, you can check the input, output to see what went wrong. But I don't know how to debug this SQL code. Sorry for so many questions. Thank you for your time.